# if using shared memory, are there still advantages for processes over threading?

Tags: c, posix, process, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have written a Linux application in which the main 'consumer' process forks off a bunch of 'reader' processes (~16) which read data from the disk and pass it to the 'consumer' for display.  The data is passed over a socket which was created before the fork using socketpair.

I originally wrote it with this process boundary for 3 reasons:

1. The consumer process has real-time constraints, so I wanted to avoid any memory allocations in the consumer.  The readers are free to allocate memory as they wish, or even be written in another language (e.g. with garbage collection), and this doesn't interrupt the consumer, which has FIFO priority.  Also, disk access or other IO in the reader process won't interrupt the consumer.  I figured that with threads I couldn't get such guarantees.
2. Using processes will stop me, the programmer, from doing stupid things like using global variables and clobbering other processes' memory.
3. I figured forking off a bunch of workers would be the best way to utilize multiple CPU architectures, and I figured using processes instead of threads would generally be safer.

Not all readers are always active, however, those that are active are constantly sending large amounts of data.  Lately I was thinking that to optimize this by avoiding memory copies associated with writing and reading the socket, it would be nice to just read the data directly into a shared memory buffer (shm_open/mmap).  Then only an index into this shared memory would be passed over the socket, and the consumer would read directly from it before marking it as available again.

Anyways, one of the biggest benefits of processes over threads is to *avoid* clobbering another thread's memory space.  Do you think that switching to shared memory would destroy any advantages I have in this architecture?  Is there still any advantage to using processes in this context, or should I just switch my application to using threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption that you cannot meet your realtime constraints with threads is mistaken. IO or memory allocation in the reader threads cannot stall the consumer thread as long as the consumer thread is not using `malloc` itself (which could of course lead to lock contention). I would recommend reading what [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_08) has to say on the matter if you're unsure.

As for the other reasons to use processes instead of threads (safety, possibility of writing the readers in a different language, etc.), these are perfectly legitimate. As long as your consumer process treats the shared memory buffer as potentially-unsafe external data, I don't think you lose any significant amount of safety by switching from pipes to shared memory.

Comment: Really? Somehow I was under the impression that if `malloc` feels the need to expand the heap size using `sbrk`, it can cause the whole process to stall.  Similarly if a thread is doing memory operations that create a page fault, it can stall all threads in the process.  Maybe that's wrong?

Comment: That's wrong. It only stalls the thread. Strictly speaking this is an implementation detail (except perhaps on systems that conform to the POSIX realtime option?), but no sane implementation would allow any of these operations to stall other threads. Certainly on Linux, the BSDs, and any other mainstream Unix it's only the thread that gets stalled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly for the reason you told. It's better to have each processes memory protected and only share what is really necessary to share. So each consumer can allocate and use its resources without bothering with the locking.

As for your index communication between your task, it should be noted that you could then use an area in your shared memory for that and using mutex for the accesses, as it is likely less heavy than the socket communication. File descriptor communication (sockets, pipes, files etc) always involves the kernel, shared memory with mutex locks or semaphores only when there is contention.

One point to be aware of when programming with shared memory in a multiprocessor environment, is to avoid false dependencies on variables. This happens when two unrelated objects share the same cache line. When one is modified it "dirties" also the other, which means that if other processor access the other object it will trigger a cache synchronisation between the CPUs. This can lead to bad scaling. By aligning the objects to the cache line size (64 byte usually but can differ from architecture to architecture) one can easily avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

The main reason I met in my experience to replace processes by threads was efficiency.
If your processes are using a lot of code or unshared memory that could be shared in multithreading, then you could win a lot of performance on highly threaded CPUs like SUN Sparc CPUs having 64 or more threads per CPU. In this case, the CPU cache, especially for the code, will be much more efficient with multithreaded process (cache is small on Sparc).

If you see that your software is not running faster when running on new hardware with more CPU threads, then you should consider multi-threading. Otherwise, your arguments to avoid it seem good to me.

I did not meet this issue on Intel processors yet, but it could happen in the future when they add more cores per CPU.

Comment: As long as your archtecture uses a physically-mapped cache (as both SPARC and x86 / x86-64 do), then the same code segment mapped into multiple processes will have the same cache advantange.